# Extracting contours after watershed algorithm

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, watershed

I have a [certain image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LVTu.png) on which I have applied watershed algorithm and obtained satisfactory results. I have used OpenCV and C++ to obtain the result.  Now, how do I go about extracting the segmented sections and preferably saving them as contours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to do it!  [Contours after watershed algorithm](http://answers.opencv.org/question/75557/how-to-draw-contours-of-each-segmented-object/) This solves my problem.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.